# Reliable and secure method for tweeting by mail?

Tags: webapp-rec

I know it is a weird way of tweeting but I want to tweet by e-mail. There are some web applications doing this, but I am looking for a credible and secure method of doing this.

Comment: Is there an issue with the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest app for this is **TwitterMail**: 
http://twittercounter.com/pages/twittermail

I feel like it has the biggest following, and best combination of features / ease of use.

**Other Solutions include:** 
http://tweetymail.com/
http://www.tweetbymail.com/
http://tweettoemail.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Posterous](http://posterous.com) isn't exactly a tweet by email app. But you can use it to do that if you really need to!
Just configure it to autopost your posts to your twitter account.